# Missing errorbars when using yscale('log') at matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

In some cases matplotlib shows plot with errorbars errorneously when using logarithmic scale. 
Suppose these data (within pylab for example):

```
s=[19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 24.0]
v=[36.5, 66.814250000000001, 130.17750000000001, 498.57466666666664, 19.41]
verr=[0.28999999999999998, 80.075044597909169, 71.322124839818571, 650.11015891565125, 0.02]
errorbar(s,v,yerr=verr)
```

and I get a normal result but when I switch to logarithmic scale:

```
yscale('log')
```

I get a plot in which some errorbars are not visible, although you can still see some of the error bar caps. (See below.) Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

[image: log plot example]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that for some points `v-verr` is becoming negative, values <=0 cannot be shown on a logarithmic axis (`log(x)`, `x<=0` is undefined) To get around this you can use asymmetric errors and force the resulting values to be above zero for the offending points.

At any point for which errors are bigger than value `verr>=v` we assign `verr=.999v` in this case the error bar will go close to zero.

Here is the script

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

s=[19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 24.0]
v=np.array([36.5, 66.814250000000001, 130.17750000000001, 498.57466666666664, 19.41])
verr=np.array([0.28999999999999998, 80.075044597909169, 71.322124839818571,     650.11015891565125, 0.02])
verr2 = np.array(verr)
verr2[verr>=v] = v[verr>=v]*.999999
plt.errorbar(s,v,yerr=[verr2,verr])
plt.ylim(1E1,1E4)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result

[image: Logarithmic plot with error bars]

Answer (score 23):

Switch to logarithmic scale, but with this command:

```
plt.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```

Analogously, for the x-axis:

```
plt.xscale('log', nonposx='clip')
```

Anyway, if you got a [dev version of matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master) in the last half year, you would have this clipping behavior by default, as discussed in [Make nonposy='clip' default for log scale y-axes](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2147).

Comment: This is really the right answer.  Much simpler than Dan's solution.