# Horizontal lines in errorbars disappearing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having some troubles with errorbars in ggplot (R) similar to [this problem in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491829/missing-errorbars-when-using-yscalelog-at-matplotlib).
My horizontal errobars are disappearing when using the `scale_y` function. Can you help me find a solution? The [data is here](http://aeblerov.com/yeast_sac.txt).

My code is:

```
data_sac_ggplot <- ggplot(yeast_sac, aes(x=factor(day), y=mean_count, colour=yeastsample, group=c("low","high"))) +
  scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  geom_line(size=0.8) +
  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, fill="white") +
  theme_bw()
data_sac_ggplot + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_count-low, ymax=mean_count+high), width=0.1, position=pd)
data_sac_ggplot + scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,1000000000))
```

Thanks!

[Picture of plot:](http://aeblerov.com/example_sac.png)

Comment: Have a look at your data file. I get an error when trying to read it: `In read.table("http://aeblerov.com/yeast_sac.txt", sep = "\t"): incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'http://aeblerov.com/yeast_sac.txt'`. It looks like everything is in one row.

Comment: Where is that `pd` object?

Comment: After manually fixing your data, I get another error: `Error in is.vector(breaks) : could not find function "trans_breaks"`. Where did read about that function? It doesn't seem to exist in `ggplot2`...

Comment: @Jaap trans_breaks is in package {scales}

Comment: There are two things missing in your sample dataset: the `pd` variable (as already mentioned by @GeorgeDontas) and the `high` variable. Please provide a dataset with all needed variables, else it's very hard to replicate your problem and thus give an answer which solves your problem.

Comment: @GeorgeDontas the *pd* object was originally defined as *pd<-position_dodge(0.1)*, but since it doesn't mean anything here I have removed it

Comment: probably the same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936112/rescaling-the-y-axis-in-bar-plot-causes-bars-to-disappear-r-ggplot2

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks, but it doesn't seem possible to use coord cartesian to change to log scales..